# Latex preamble in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have read several discussions and threads detailing how to add latex pre-amble to R markdown, but am yet to find an easy explanation of how to add latex pre-amble to Rmd files. I have templates in latex that I want to use in my Rmd's PDF and Beamer outputs.

I am having great difficulty in adding pre-amble arguments.

I tried:

```
in_header
<latex preamble>
```

as well as

```
%%
<preamble>
%%
```

But none seem to work.

Any solutions to someone experienced with latex, but far less with using rmd?

Comment: Have you tried to open and close the preamble with a line of `$$`?

Comment: @CathG, Rmd uses neither of those commands. It can producea latex file and I can input the pre-amble hard code, but that's not ideal..

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this?

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "All of Us"
date: "Today, November 2, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx, verbatim, fancyvrb, setspace, xspace, colortbl, longtable, amsmath, caption, xfrac, float, mathabx}
---
```

where you can include pieces in the "`header-includes`" portion?

Comment: I have since resorted to changing the latex template directly. header-includes works only for including packages, not figures and other adjustments. Though once you adjust the latex tamplate files, it works perfectly. This can be done by adjusting, e.g., ~R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/templates - I suggest copying and renaming the folder, whereafter adjusting the templates (in resources folder) as well as the skeleton to conform to your own standards, if someone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `in_header` argument to specify the path to a preamble document.

Note that some things you might list in a preamble file can be specified directly, for example options to the `geometry` package:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "All of Us"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
geometry: "a4paper,right=6cm"
---
```